# $U_{p^2}$ a group under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$ be prime and define $U_{p^2} = \{[a]_{p^2} \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} : p \nmid a\}$. Note $U_{p^2}$ is a group under multiplication.

(i) What is the identity element of $U_{p^2}$? ( I think this could be $[0]_{p^2}$)

(ii) Use the statement in (a)(i) to give a proof that axiom (G3) holds for $U_{p^2}$.
((G3) Given $h\in H$, we need to check that $h^{-1}\in H$.)

(iii) Show that $|U_{p^2}|= p(p−1)$.

I really don't understand this topic and the text book gives the example above for us to try out but i just don't know where to start. Would really appreciate any help or understanding of the above question or topic. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Don't you have a guess for (i)?  For (ii), you should tell us what axiom G3 is.  For (iii), note that, of the $p^2$ integers from $0$ to $p^2-1$, $p$ of them are divisible by $p$

Comment: $[0]_{p^2}$ is not in $U_{p^2}$, so guess again

Comment: I suggest you start by writing out the set explcitly when $p=3$.

Comment: What is in $U_{p^2}$, I don't understand how to work this out

Comment: Do you know what is in $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ ?

Comment: The integers im guessing or does the $p^2$ require that it has to be the squares in the integers

Comment: I think $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ means integers modulo $p^2$

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, $U_{p^2}=\{a\in\Bbb Z_{p^2}\mid\operatorname{gcd}(a,p^2)=1\}$ is the multiplicative group or the integers modulo $p^2$. Therefore, $U_{p^2}$ is made of the integers (equivalence classes) from $1$ to $p^2-1$ *which are not multiple of $p$* (as for these latter $\operatorname{gcd}(a,p^2)=p\ne1$). Now, $np\le p^2-1\iff n\le p-\frac{1}{p}$, so for $n=1,\dots,p-1$. From this, it follows that $|U_{p^2}|=p^2-1-(p-1)=p(p-1)$. This answers iii).

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) for further reference on this group.